# How to set environment variable which is in bash for my executable using CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, bash, cmake, environment-variables, setenv

I have a set of an environment variable which is in bash, I want to add those all environment variable in my executable in CMakeLists.txt.

I have an exec-cluster.bash file having

```
 EXPORTS+=" export DICE_USE_ALT_LICENSE=${DICE_USE_ALT_LICENSE};"
 EXPORTS+=" export DICE_VENDOR_KEY=\"${DICE_VENDOR_KEY}\";"
```

Now I want to add these all variable in my executable in CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: You can change the environment of a process (your running executable) but AFAIK you cannot change the enviroment of a parent process (the `bash` in your case). The only exception might be to change one of the start scripts (e.g. `~/.bashrc`) but even then the changes won't become effective before `bash` is started next time. Btw. how do you know that user of your executable runs this from `bash`? Although it's probably very common - it's not the only existing shell. `tcsh` and `zsh` might be in use as well and there are (much?) more...

Comment: what do u mean by "adding env vars to the executable"?

Comment: I am using get_env("DICE_USE_ALT_LICENSE") in my source code and  that environment variable DICE_USE_ALT_LICENSE defined in exec-cluster.bash. so I want to add exec-cluster.bash in CMakeLists.txt while building my source so that I can use.

Comment: but `get_env` only applies when your program **runs**, not when is being **built**? How would CMake come into the picture here? Do you want to hard-code these variables into your program somehow?

Comment: Then how can I make the environment ready for my executable so that I can use while environment variables are defined in bash?

Comment: Are you calling the bash script as part of your build process, or do you need these envvars defined for the end user running the software?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the environment variable inside cmake with `$ENV{}` and then add them to the compile environment as C/C++ defines:

```
...
set(VARIABLE_VAL $ENV{VARIABLE_NAME})

add_compile_definitions(VARIABLE_NAME=${VARIABLE_VAL})
...
```

If I understood well what you want...